# Can't change entrycell value at runtime using FindbyName<EntryCell>("txtCell")

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Hey Good Day Im really having a hard time trying to change the value of entrycell at run time my code goes this way:

reg.xaml

```
              <TableSection Title="CREDENTIAL">
                <EntryCell Label="Username:" Text="09068100820" Keyboard="Text" />
                <EntryCell Label="Password:" x:Name="TxtPassword" Keyboard="Text" />
                <EntryCell Label="Ref Code:" x:Name="TxtRefCodes" Keyboard="Text" />
                <ViewCell>
                  <ContentView Padding="0,0">
                    <ContentView.Padding>
                      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="10,0" WinPhone="0,15,0,0" />
                    </ContentView.Padding>
                    <ContentView.Content>
                      <Button x:Name="BntRegz" Clicked="BntRegz_OnClicked" BackgroundColor="#fd6d6d" Text="SUBMIT" TextColor="White"/>

                    </ContentView.Content>
                  </ContentView>
                </ViewCell>

              </TableSection>
```

reg.xaml.cs

```
        private void BntRegz_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        var txt = this.FindByName<EntryCell>("TxtPassword");
        txt.Text = "Test This";
        }
```

Thanks a lot in advance. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, but `Placeholder` is only shown if the `EntryCell` is empty.

Example:

```
private void BntRegz_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txt = this.FindByName<EntryCell>("TxtRefCodes");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Placeholder))
    {
        txt.Placeholder = "EntryCell is Empty";
    }
    else
    {
        txt.Text = "Overwrite value entered by user";
    }
}
```

Empty `TxtRefCodes` Entry and user clicks Submit, `Placeholder` is shown:

[image]

User enters text into `TxtRefCodes`:

[image]

User clicks Submit and his entry is overwritten:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work on my project thank u anyway the image above i updated everytime I click the button it doesnt show up anything on the textbox. And the debug msgs ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION DOWN

Comment: @jaketalledo `ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION DOWN` that is an Android issue, what version of `Xamarin.Android` and `Xamarin.Forms` are you using?

Comment: :( wait i got to try to change with my Android/SDK in Tools->xamarin->sdk as i have been using Android Studio SDK